# Accord du participe passé avec le sujet

Tags: accord, participe-passé, passé-composé

Is it the past tense for revenir :

> i) Nous (hommes) sommes revenus
>
> ii) Nous (femmes) sommes revenues

is it correct ?

Comment: Depends on the gender of the subject. If *nous* is a group of men or is mixed, use the first one. If it's a group of only women/girls, use the second one.

Answer (score 3):

Tous les deux sont corrects.

> i) Nous sommes revenus.

Ceux qui sont revenus ne sont que des hommes. S'il s'agit d'un groupe d'hommes et femmes c'est l'emploi dudit masculin générique.

Those who have returned are only men. If it is a group of men and women it is the use of the so-called generic masculine.

> ii) Nous sommes revenues.

Des femmes sont revenues.

Les verbes conjugués avec être comme auxiliaire nécessitent l'accord du participe passé. Cf.

The verbs conjugated with être as auxiliary require the agreement of the past participle. Cf.

> Elle a mangé ; il a mangé ; elles ont mangé ; ils ont mangé
>
> Elle est parti**e** ; il est parti ; elles sont parti**es** ; ils sont
>   parti**s**.

**EDIT** (merci @Laurent S.)

*"Les verbes conjugués avec être comme auxiliaire nécessitent l'accord du participe passé" > Il faut rajouter "avec le sujet", parce que l'on accorde aussi le participe passé des verbes utilisant l'auxiliaire avoir, les règles d'accord sont juste différentes...*

Comment: "Les verbes conjugués avec être comme auxiliaire nécessitent l'accord du participe passé avec le sujet" A L'EXCEPTION de certains verbes pronominaux.